# "Invalid value for schema path" error when assigning schemas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my `nodejs` app I have one schema defined in file as module:

```
let schema_pool_jobs = new mongoose.Schema({
   task_name : String,
   params    : Object,
   status    : String,
   progress  : Number
});
module.exports.schema_pool_jobs = schema_pool_jobs;
```

Then in another file I "require" this module and use it inside `connectToMongo` function to bind collections to schema:

```
let schemas = require(path_to_schema_file);

let connectToMongo = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let conn = mongoose.createConnection(CONFIG.MONGO_DB, {
         useMongoClient: true
      });
      conn.on("open", () => {
         console.log("connected");
         conn.model("pool_jobs", schemas.schema_pool_jobs, "pool_jobs");
         return resolve();
      });
      conn.on("error", error => reject(error));
   });
}

connectToMongo();
```

But as soon as I run it I see

```
connected
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `paths.task_name.regExp`
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:383:13)
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:396:14)
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:396:14)
    at new Schema (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:105:10)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.model (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:1034:14)
    at NativeConnection.mongoose.project.on (evalmachine.<anonymous>:37:32)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at open (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:738:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:747:5)
    at C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:707:11
    at C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:227:5
    at C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:239:5
    at ReplSet.connectHandler (C:\Users\xxx\dev\project\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:343:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

And I cannot find any reasonable explanation what it means and why this is happening. Any ideas how to fix it?

I am using mongoose `4.8.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to figure out what was going on.
It turned out that I was creating schemas **before** I `required` mongoose and that caused brain twist for mongoose.
As soon as I first required `mongoose` and then defined schemas everything went ok.